# WordPress multisite network with non-wp site at domain

Tags: wordpress, dns, subdomain, multisite

I want to set up a multisite network using subdomains under a domain that is used for a non-wp site.

so, for example, we want our domains to look like:
blog1.mysite.com
blog2.mysite.com
but mysite.com points to our main site that is not built with WordPress and is not part of this network.

I'm not sure what to do here since the main domain, site.com in this case, typically points to the root blog on the multisite network.

I suspect this is common and there is a simple solution but I'm not sure where to start.

**Update (unresolved) :**
I've had a little bit of luck working on this locally but I'm still not out of the water...

my dilemma… I need to set up multisite with subdomains under a domain that is not part of the network? So basically, we have our main site: mainsite.com
and we want to set up a network with subdomains like site1.mainsite.com and site2.mainsite.com.

mainsite.com, however is not a WordPress site and is not part of the network. so If I set the network up under multisite.mainsite.com, then new sites subdomains are created with that as the subdomain like: site1.multisite.mainsite.com

but if I set the current site to mainsite.com, then all of the network admin links break because they point to our main non-wp site.

So, here's what I've done, which kinda works (I'm doing everything locally with my hosts file so I won't know for sure until I get it on a dev box) ...

- First I pointed mainsite.com to my local ip in my hosts file and set the network up under mainsite.com
- Next I successfully created two sites. multisite.mainsite.com and site1.mainsite.com, through the network admin panel
- Then, I changed the 'current site' in wp-config.php from mainsite.com to multisite.mainsite.com and I removed mainsite.com from my hosts file.
- Now, I can go to mainsite.com and land on our primary website; I can go to site1.mainsite.com and land on the wordpress site on the network; and I can access the network-admin-section under multisite.mainsite.com
- The problem is, since the current site is multisite.mainsite.com, if I try to add a new site to the network, the domain will be site3.multisite.mainsite.com instead of the intended site3.mainsite.com

So I still haven't found the correct solution here but this might help explain my problem a little better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out... I didn't realize previously that you can manually change the site url in the site edit screen. Here's a write up with more details: http://georgespake.com/create-a-multisite-network-using-sub-domains-under-an-existing-domain/